# Math In Android?

Tags: android, math

How can I write this in math function in Android, im stuck on how to multiply things and use atan2:

```
Math.atan2(posY, posX) * 180/Math.PI;
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Android version of Math has atan2 and PI.

Comment: @JeffLemon Would you be so kind to select a correct answer to this and other questions you asked in stackoverflow? If people spend time trying to help you, it is reasonable to ask for some feedback on your part. Thank you.

Comment: Just so you know, there's a `Math.toDegrees()` function in the API.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
((Math.atan2(posY, posX)) * 180)/Math.PI
```

Answer (score 2):

You imported `java.lang.Math`, correct?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 2):

`Atan2` is generally used to find the angle from one point to another.
Usually the parameters are the Y-difference between the two points
and the X-difference between the two points:

```
 double deltaX=endX-startX;
 double deltaY=endY-startY;
 double angleInDegrees=Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

The conversion to degrees (`* 180 / Math.PI`) is needed because 
`atan2` returns radians, not degrees.